# Functions problems and optimisation problems

Tags: functions

The cost of some product is $40.

Currently its retail price is $60 and the quantity of sale is 300 per week.

Now you want to make a promotion and find that for each $1 that you reduce the price you can sell 20 more per week.

(a) Let x be price after promotion. Find the formula for benefit B(x) per week.

(b) Optimize B(x) and find out the best promotion price x and benefit.

What I did for part (a) is using the equation y = mx + c

where y = 300, 
x = $60, 
c = $40

300 = 60m + 40

60m = 300 - 40

m = 260/ 60

m = 13/3

y = 13/3 x + 40

I wanted to know if I am on the right track so that I can proceed with the part (b)

Comment: Welcome to the site ! Please, understand that many people here are willing to **help** provided you show what you already tried, expalin where you are stuck and so on. I strngly recommend you update your post **now**.

Comment: So what i did is 

using the equation y = mx + c

Then 

300 = m(60) + 40

60m + 40 = 300

m = 260/60

y = 13/2 x + 40

Comment: I want to know if what i did is right so that i can proceed.
if not can you guide me how to work it out.
Thanks

Comment: You should make an edit with your work instead of putting it in comments. - And remember to tell what each of the variables/functions (i.e.$x$, $y$,$m$ and $c$) is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'd use a second degree equation,

ax²+bx+c

And then profit P of increase in price would basically be the product between

(i) 300 + 20x,

which is how many products you're going to sell for a given decrease in price, and

(ii) 60 - x

which is the new price. (Though keep in mind that, to get profit you'ld have to subtract 40 of (ii) otherwise you'ld assume that the product is free to produce).

So: (i) * (ii)

Rest is up to you, but the easiest way is to use derivatives, whom you may or may not be familiar with...

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: I just wanted to know if the value of x can be negative?

Answer (score 0):

If the price after promotion is $\$(60 - t)$, then $300 + 20t$ units are sold per week.  Hence, when the price is lowered by $\$t$, revenue in dollars is 
$$R(t) = (60 - t)(300 + 20t)$$
Since each unit costs $\$40$, the profit in dollars when the price is lowered $\$t$ is 
$$P(t) = (60 - 40 - t)(300 + 20t) = (20 - t)(300 + 20t)$$
Use the formula for $P(t)$ to determine the maximum profit and the value of $t$ at which it occurs.  The desired price is then $60 - t$.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: I just wanted to know if the value of x can be negative?

Answer (score 0):

Since we have **defined** x to be a decrease, hence -x, directly in the equation, and you'd put in a negative value for x:

-(-x) = x

Which would give the effect of increasing the price